# Windows Command | Split A File to Contain and Doesn't Contain By Other File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compare, findstr

I have 2 files: tempfile.txt & mainfile.txt. I would like to parse tempfile and check whether the strings in it exists in mainfile. If they do, I would like to put the string in contain.txt. If not, they should be placed in dcontain.txt

When I run the script below, dcontain.txt file does not get created. Instead, all the search strings end up in contain.txt.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (tempfile.txt) do (
findstr /m "%%a" mainfile.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo %%a>>contain.txt
)else (
echo %%a>>dcontain.txt
)
)
```

Please see below the contents of mainfile, tempfile and what should contain.txt and dcontain.txt should include. The last column is what I see instead.

```
mainfile  tempfile   contain   dcontain |O|contain.txt
11111     11111      11111     aaaaa    |U|11111 
22222     aaaaa      22222     bbbbb    |T|aaaaa       
33333     22222      33333              |O|22222   
44444     bbbbb                         |U|bbbbb      
55555     33333                         |T|33333
```

Comment: You are using Turkish characters which make it quite possible to use @ to address you. Also, the question is very difficult to understand the way it was posed but including contents of the file was useful to figure out what you meant to do.

Comment: Try this: `findstr /M /C:"%%a" "mainfile.txt" > nul && (>> "contain.txt" echo(%%a) || (>> "dcontain.txt" echo(%%a)`...

Comment: Thank You @AdilHindistan ! it's worked! I tried many different way but i never think enabledelayedexpansion :) hmm maybe because i'm new on batch :D thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch is a finicky beast and there are a couple of subtle problems with the way you are doing this. %ERRORLEVEL% expansion happens at parse time within DO block, so it is evaluated only once and you do not get 0 and 1 as you would expect.

Setting `enabledelayedexpansion` helps with that. When you are checking for equality, `EQU` and `NEQ` are the "numeric" operators, while `==` would be used for string comparison.

You can make your code work if you change it as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (tempfile.txt) do (
findstr /I "%%a" mainfile.txt >nul 2>&1

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (

    echo %%a>>dcontain.txt  

)else (

    echo %%a>>contain.txt   
)
)
```

Comment: it's works on low size file but I have 2 large txt file and i can't get results. main file has 10k lines temp file has 2k lines. and some strings contain in main file when parse dcontain.txt @AdilHindistan

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, and based purely upon your provided content, you should be able to do that without a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```bat
FindStr /IG:"tempfile.txt" "mainfile.txt">"contain.txt"
FindStr /VIG:"mainfile.txt" "tempfile.txt">"dcontain.txt"
```

*Note:*
When you use `/G` the content of the first line of the file determines whether the searches are performed as literal strings or regular expressions. Obviously as you provided the content I saw no need to specificaly tell it which to use as your content did not contain regular expression characters. Perhaps therefore you should use the `/L` option and just to ensure that exact matches only are used the `/X` option too. To find out which options are available, open up a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?`.

```bat
FindStr /XLIG:"tempfile.txt" "mainfile.txt">"contain.txt"
FindStr /XVLIG:"mainfile.txt" "tempfile.txt">"dcontain.txt"
```

Comment: @İzzettinAlpaslan, then you have not copied the above code correctly, or you are not using the same file content as provided in your question, _and I quite clearly stated, "based purely upon your provided content"_.

Comment: @İzzettinAlpaslan, I have added a note to the foot of my answer to see if it helps you further. Oh, and please do not accept an answer, then comment that it doesn't work for you without removing that acceptance. Nobody including that answerer will feel compelled to provide you with the further assistance you need. Also [tag:findstr] expects that your files are correctly terminated, _(with the empty line at the bottom)_.